# "does not live long enough" error when iterating through a linked list

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a linked list and an iterator to iterate through the list.

```
enum List<T> {
    Cons(T, Box<List<T>>),
    Nil,
}

struct ListIterator<'a, T:'a> {
    cur: &'a List<T>
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator<T> for ListIterator<'a, T> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T>{
        match self.cur {
            &Cons(val, next) => {self.cur = &*next; Some(val)},
            &Nil => None
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
error: `*next` does not live long enough
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message points to a real issue, but there is actually another one that the compiler should report instead because it comes earlier. In your match arm

```
&Cons(val, next) => {self.cur = &*next; Some(val)},
```

you are trying to destructure a List object into `&Cons(val,next)` which is an attempt to move `val` and `next` out from behind a borrowed pointer. This is not allowed. But if it were, `val` and `next` would be local variables with a rather short lifetime. The error message you see is because of that: next would be a local box that is about to be dropped. Hence the type of `&*next` is a reference with a lifetime parameter referring to the lifetime of this local box. And that's too short to return it.

This calls for the use of `ref` and `box` patterns:

```
&Cons(ref val, box ref next) => { self.cur = next; Some(*val) },
```

Now, `val` is of type `&T` and `next` is of type `&List` where both are references into your list data structure and nothing is moved out. Note also, that `Some(*val)` requires `T` to be `Copy`:

```
impl<'a, T: Copy> Iterator<T> for ListIterator<'a, T> {
...
```

But `Copy` is quite a requirement. A more general way would be to use `Clone` like this:

```
impl<'a, T: Clone> Iterator<T> for ListIterator<'a, T> {
...
    &Cons(ref val, box ref next) => { self.cur = next; Some((*val).clone()) },
```

This works for more types. And if you don't want to clone the values, you could also make your iterator yield `&T` instead of `T` just like it's done with vectors and slices.

Comment: This doesn't work.
It seems that I don't have right to dereference val.
Link to the test code: http://is.gd/DzoqHl

Comment: @lovasoa: It works for me if I add the `Copy` bound for T. As I said, T needs to be `Copy`.

Comment: @lovasoa: Clone is more general than Copy. But you probably should implement `Iterator<&T>` instead of `Iterator<T>`. See my updated answer.